# Does Abelianization Commute with Profinite Completion?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, let $\widehat{G}$ be its profinite completion, and let $G^{\text{ab}}$ be its abelianization.

Is is true that abelianization commutes with profinite completion, in the sense that $(\widehat{G})^{\text{ab}} = \widehat{G^{\text{ab}}}$?

Comment: I think it may depend on exactly what you mean by the abelianization of a profinite group. The commutator subgroup of a profinite group is not in general closed, so the abelianization in the category of profinite groups (i.e., the quotient by the *closure* of the commutator subgroup) may be different from the abelianization as an abstract group. If you mean the topological abelianization, then I think the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response! Here is a somewhat related question: does abelianization commute with infinite products? I think the answer is yes, even if one does not take closures of the commutator subgroups, but I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: The product of abelianizations can be a proper quotient of the abelianization of the product, in general. Suppose for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a group $G_n$ with an element $x_n$ that is the product of $n$ commutators but no fewer. Then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}G_n$ is in the product of the commutator subgroups of the $G_n$, but not in the commutator subgroup of the product.